# Flutter: What option is there to assign variable? to variable - null can't be assigned to non-null; path_provider getExternalStorageDirectory();

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, path-provider

Testing for something that might not exist, is spawning risk of a null
but what is the option to acknowledge that and assign good results to a non-null variable?

For example [path_provider getExternalStorageDirectory();] might reasonably respond null in the case there is no external storage.

How can a Directory be assigned, if it does exist, with that risk that might null?

Assigning a temporary variable to test for the null, doesn't work.

Error is consistently then

> A value of type 'Directory?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Directory'.

Comment: I do not fully understand the question.  Are you asking how to check if a variable is null, only proceed if it is non-null, and at that point handle it as a non-nullable type?

Comment: Yes, to assign the reply from getExternalStorageDirectory() that is Directory? to a variable that is Directory.

Comment: You either make the variable nullable or you make it `late` and initialize it later.  However, making it `late` means that you must guarantee that it is initialized before anything accesses it.

Comment: Depending on your scenario, you can define a default that will be used in case the nullable is indeed null, example:
```stringLength = str?.length ?? 0```

Answer (score 0):

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` return nullable `Directory`  from future, you can make data type as nullable.

```dart
Directory? directory =  await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Find more about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Obviously you can make a variable nullable to accept the return! The question is about how to get rid of the nullable. Forcing a cascade just because of one nullable, mismatching everything else, seems odd. There should be option to purge the null?

Comment: I prefer not forcing it as non-nullable, null-safety is safe IMO, you can do `Directory directory =  await getExternalStorageDirectory()!;` but when it return null, you will ended up another error. you can check attach link for more

Answer (score 0):

Reading replies then as "nullable forces nullable", which is workable but odd there is not that option to remove the null.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).